# Jquery ui tooltip not working

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to test out the jquery-ui's tooltip to no avail.  Here is what I did: https://jsfiddle.net/o99ua97c/.  But it is not working and I couldn't quite figure out why.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){});
    $('#myINPUT').tooltip({
        function() {
            content: return 'tooltip from jquery-ui';
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="myINPUT">Enter Something</label>
    <input type="text" size="20" id="myINPUT"/>
</body>
```

Comment: ok.  This is weird.  I got it to work in the jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/o99ua97c/4/.  Seems like it requires the title attribute to be present for it to work.  But here is the weird part.  It does not work in https.  so, this work: http://jsfiddle.net/o99ua97c/4/.  But this does not (notice the https protocol): https://jsfiddle.net/o99ua97c/4/.

Answer (score 0):

The document ready should be around the tooltip call. The tooltip is called to early now.

Edit, there seem to be some other problems as well.